# PHPMailer sends email but not shows the emails returned

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

My PHPMailer function sends emails correctly, but i don't have the way to check if this emails have been received correctly. For example, if I use a fake email address like asnfafas@jlsgnsg.com, PHPMailer returns true in $mail->Send() because the email has been sent, but obviusly this email will not arrive to this email address, so have been returned. How can I detect this returned emails?

I looked into PHPMailer library but i don't find a functionality that detect this returned emails. Can i use some PHPMailer tool or I have to use another library?

Thanks

Comment: SMTP is different than other protocols in that the originator and he destination are connected by several distinct hops, and the message can fail at each hop. For you, PHPMailer is successfully handling the message over to the next hop, and then ceasing to exist. If a message fails, PHPMailer no longer exists and can’t report on anything. Instead, the next hop will usually send a bounce message back, and you can control this by setting the `Sender` property. Not every MTA will bounce every failed message, however.

Comment: `i don't have the way to check if this emails have been received correctly`...yep, that's how email works unfortunately. It's like posting a letter...you put it into the postbox and then it's someone else's responsibility, you can't check what happens. But unlike the postal system there's no equivalent of all-the-way-through parcel tracking for important messages. As mentioned above, the best you might get is a bounceback from one of the servers en-route, but that's not guaranteed. And if a message is filtered out as spam or anything like that, that is very likely to happen entirely silently.

Comment: It helps to get onto good terms with your local mail server. Errors like nonexistent domains and unknown users are often spotted very early in the email delivery chain, and it's likely that your email server will see them, so look into bounce processing and make use of the `Sender` property in PHPMailer to route those bounces to where you want them to go (most usefully into another PHP script that can parse them).